Select Id from TextField when select property is enabled in MUI?
I'm trying to get id from mui TextFiled element when select property is enabled. I'm getting undefined vlaue always
code:
export default ({
    onChangeSelect,
    input,
    label,
    options,
    name,
    required,
    placeholder,
    id
}) => {
    return <TextField
        value={input}
        onChange={onChangeSelect}
        select
        id={id}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        label={label}
        name={name}
        required={required}
        InputLabelProps={{ shrink: (placeholder || input), style: { fontSize: 16 } }}
    >
        {options.map(data => <MenuItem key={data.name} value={data.value}>{data.name}</MenuItem>)}
    </TextField>
}


const handleIdCode = useCallback((e) => {
        const { name, value, id } = e.target
        console.log(name, value, id, 'test') // here id is undefined
})


I have debugged and passed id value to menu item and getting it from handler in the following way
solution:
export default ({
    onChangeSelect,
    input,
    label,
    options,
    name,
    required,
    placeholder,
    id
}) => {
    return <TextField
        value={input}
        onChange={onChangeSelect}
        select
        placeholder={placeholder}
        label={label}
        name={name}
        required={required}
        InputLabelProps={{ shrink: (placeholder || input), style: { fontSize: 16 } }}
    >
        {options.map(data => <MenuItem id={id} key={data.name} value={data.value}>{data.name}</MenuItem>)} // added id here in menu item
    </TextField>
}

const handleIdCode = useCallback((e, item) => { // added item has second params
        const { name, value, id } = e.target
        console.log(name, value, item?.props?.id, 'test') from the item getting id in this way
    })

